# std::isgraph asserts, how to fix?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17, locale

Im getting the following assert when calling [`std::isgraph`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph):

```
_ASSERTE(c >= -1 && c <= 255);
```

It's a unicode built on Windows platform, but the locale is reported as "c". What should I set the locale to in order to support unicode ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

`std::isgraph` has nothing to do with Unicode.

In particular, it cannot support any character value out of the range you've mentioned.

You could pass it individual bytes of a [say, UTF-8] codepoint, sure, but that wouldn't tell you anything.

It's simply not designed for what you're trying to do.

Use a proper library like ICU instead.