# 架 (U+67B6) is not graphical with en_US.UTF-8. Whats going on?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17, locale

This is a follow up question to:

[std::isgraph asserts, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138426)

After setting locale to "en_US.UTF-8", [`std::isgraph`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph) no longer asserts.

However, the unicode character 架 (U+67B6) is reported as `false` in the same function. What is going on ?

It's a unicode built on Windows platform.

Comment: [`std::isgraph`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph) _The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF_.

Comment: Can you provide the exact code that causes the failure?

Comment: I can only guess what you want to achieve. You should examine the Unicode properties of a character instead of using legacy interfaces. `› uniprops 架␤U+67B6 ‹架› \N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-67B6}␤\w \pL \p{Lo}␤All Alnum X_POSIX_Alnum Alpha X_POSIX_Alpha Alphabetic Any Assigned ID_Continue Is_IDC CJK CJK_Unified_Ideographs InCJK L Lo Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Han Hani IDC ID_Start IDS Ideo Ideographic Letter Other_Letter Print X_POSIX_Print UIdeo Unified_Ideograph Unicode Word X_POSIX_Word XID_Continue XIDC XID_Start XIDS` / [full output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prTqy.png)

Comment: You might have better luck with the wide character version. Works on linux, at least. Dunno about Windows.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test characters that are too large to fit in an `unsigned char`, you can try using the [wide-character versions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cwctype), or a Unicode library as already suggested (Which is really the better option for portable code, as it removes any system or locale based differences in behavior).

This program:

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cwctype>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  wchar_t x = L'\u67B6';
  char *loc = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
  std::wcout << "Using locale " << loc << ".\n";
  std::wcout << "Character " << x << " is graphical: " << std::boolalpha
             << static_cast<bool>(std::iswgraph(x)) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

when compiled and ran on my Ubuntu test system, outputs

```
Using locale en_US.utf8.
Character 架 is graphical: true
```

You said you're using Windows, but I don't have a Windows computer available for testing, so I can't confirm if this'll work there or not.

Comment: So this seems to work fine with up to 16 bit, but code points above that (in another plane) seems to not work - eg.  an emoji.

Comment: @darune I believe that on Windows, `wchar_t` is only 16-bit and can thus only handle Unicode characters in the BMP.

Answer (score 1):

`std::isgraph` is not a Unicode-aware function.

It's an antiquity from C.

From [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isgraph):

> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.

It only takes `int` because .. it's an antiquity from C. Just like `std::tolower`.

You should be using something like ICU instead.